# Build an array of arrays from an array using REDUCE in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Input data**

```
const users = [{id: 1, name: 'Madou', age: 37},
  {id: 2, name: 'Fatoumata', age: 33},
  {id: 3, name: 'Amadou', age: 31}];
```

**Output**
 `[ [ 1, 'Madou', 37 ], [ 2, 'Fatoumata', 33 ], [ 3, 'Amadou', 31 ] ]`

I implemented this:

```
const _data = users.map((item) => {
  return Object.keys(item).map((value) => item[value]);
});
console.log(_data);
```

But I want to use REDUCE instead, but I don't have any how to do it

Comment: Why? `.map` is *much* more appropriate than `.reduce` for your task

Comment: Yes indeed, even with ```.map```, I don't know how to do it efficiently

Comment: Why do you think `reduce` would do any better then?

Comment: `Object.values`

Comment: @deceze, It's true that I haven't done a comparative study between ```.map``` and ```.reduce```, but the way I implemented it seems a bit cumbersome to me.

Comment: That's because it is, yes. And `reduce` would make it even more so. See uminder's answer below, it hardly gets any more concise than that.

Comment: const result = users.map(e=>Object.values(e));

Comment: Thank you all for your help, ```Object.values(item)``` does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```js
const users = [{id: 1, name: 'Madou', age: 37},
  {id: 2, name: 'Fatoumata', age: 33},
  {id: 3, name: 'Amadou', age: 31}];
  
const result = users.map(o => Object.values(o));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: we can use your proposition if we know the KEYs, which is not my case. But it is true that I did not specify it in my comments

Comment: `@Mota`: I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const _data = users.reduce((acc, { id, name, age }) => {
  acc.push([id, name, age]);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.